# UISearchController - Objective C to Swift Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to subclass UISearchController so I can add a custom UISearchBar. I found a way to do this in Objective-C, but I'm struggling to do it in Swift. Here are the 2 files that accomplish this in Objective-C:

`CustomSearchController.h`

```
@interface CustomSearchController : UISearchController <UISearchBarDelegate>

@end
```

`CustomSearchController.m`

```
#import "CustomSearchController.h"
#import "CustomSearchBar.h"

@implementation CustomSearchController
{
    UISearchBar *_searchBar;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    if (_searchBar == nil) {
        _searchBar = [[CustomSearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _searchBar.delegate = self; // different from table search by apple where delegate was set to view controller where the UISearchController was instantiated or in our case where CustomSearchController was instantiated.
    }
    return _searchBar;
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if ([searchBar.text length] > 0) {
        self.active = true;
    } else {
        self.active = false;
    }
}

/*
 Since CustomSearchController is the delegate of the search bar we must implement the UISearchBarDelegate method.
 */
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"Became first responder");
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}


@end
```

The issue I'm running into is specifically with this getter:

```
-(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    if (_searchBar == nil) {
        _searchBar = [[CustomSearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _searchBar.delegate = self; // different from table search by apple where delegate was set to view controller where the UISearchController was instantiated or in our case where CustomSearchController was instantiated.
    }
    return _searchBar;
}
```

In `Swift` I believe I would be have to do something like this:

```
var customSearchBar: CustomSearchBar?

override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    get {
        if customSearchBar == nil {
            customSearchBar = CustomSearchBar()
            customSearchBar?.delegate = self
        }
        return customSearchBar!
    }
}
```

But is this the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lazy var customSearchBar: CustomSearchBar = {
    [unowned self] in
    let result = CustomSearchBar(frame:CGRectZero)
    result.delegate = self
    return result
}()

override var searchBar: UISearchBar {
    get {
        return customSearchBar
    }
}
```

The usage of `lazy` takes care of initializing the `CustomSearchBar` instance only when first accessed. Although I'm not sure that you really need that for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Don't forget `assert(customSearchBar != nil, "customSearchBar is nil!")` in the getter.